# to Parse JSON to NSArray in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

i have an json data.
i can get all items as string or dictionary, but i couldn't get "payments" item as array..
i want to get datas from "payments" and to convert NSDictionary 
i tried a few ways but i didn't make it.

> That is my JSON data.
>
> ```
> [{
>     "last_name": "aaa",
>     "course": {
>         "course_name": "bob",
>         "payments": [
>         {
>         "date": "cc",
>         },
>         {
>         "date": "dd",
>         }
>         ],
>         "course_time": "ee"
>     }
>     },
>     {
>         "last_name": "ggg",
>         "course": {
>             "course_name": "bob",
>             "payments": [{
>             "date": "ddd",
>             },
>             {
>             "date": "ff",
>             }],
>             "course_time": "hh"
>         }
> }]
> ```

And that is my code

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var errori: NSError?
    let jsonArr = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &errori) as NSArray
    for json in jsonArr {
        if let last_name = json["last_name"] as? String {
            let course = Course()
            if let courseTemp = json["course"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let course_name = courseTemp["course_name"] as? String {
                    course.course_name = course_name
                }
                var payments = course.payments
                if let paymentsTemp = json["payments"] as? NSArray {
                    println("That's OK!")
                    for payment in paymentsTemp {
                        let date = payment["date"] as String
                        let pay = payment["payment"] as String
                        payments.append(Payment(date: date, payment: pay))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

i didnt find what is wrong.. can u help me pls..?

Comment: What is going wrong? You haven't explained anything that is actually happening. All you said is what isn't happening. Tell us what IS happening.

Comment: Welcome to SO. When you post for help with a problem you need to provide specific, detailed information about what's going wrong. "...i didn't make it" is not useful. Does it compile? Does it crash when run? Does it run without crashing but fail to give you the desired results? If it gives a compiler error, or crashes, what is the line of the error? If the results are not what you expected, explain, in detail, how they differ from your expectations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did mistake in this line:

```
if let paymentsTemp = json["payments"] as? NSArray
```

In this line of code you are accessing the payments array from json dictionary. That payments array contain inside the course.

Just replace that `json["payments"]` array with `courseTemp["payments"]`

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        var errori: NSError?
        let jsonArr = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &errori) as NSArray
        for json in jsonArr {
            if let last_name = json["last_name"] as? String {
                let course = Course()
                if let courseTemp = json["course"] as? NSDictionary {
                    if let course_name = courseTemp["course_name"] as? String {
                        course.course_name = course_name
                    }
                    var payments = course.payments
                    if let paymentsTemp = courseTemp["payments"] as? NSArray {
                        println("That's OK!")
                        for payment in paymentsTemp {
                            let date = payment["date"] as String
                            let pay = payment["payment"] as String
                            payments.append(Payment(date: date, payment: pay))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
var errori: NSError?
let jsonArr = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &errori) as NSArray
for json in jsonArr {
    if let last_name = json["last_name"] as? String {
        let course = Course()
        if let courseTemp = json["course"] as? NSDictionary {
            if let course_name = courseTemp["course_name"] as? String {
                course.course_name = course_name
            }
            var payments = course.payments
            // as Ramesh_T mentioned
            if let paymentsTemp = courseTemp["payments"] as? NSArray {
                println("That's OK!")
                for payment in paymentsTemp {
                    if let paymentTemp = payment as? [String: String] {
                       let date = paymentTemp["date"]
                       let pay = paymentTemp["payment"]
                       payments.append(Payment(date: date, payment: pay))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
})
```