# Swift: How can I convert Type JSON to NSArray?

Tags: json, swift

I'm using `SwiftyJSON` to parse `JSON` data. The problem is, is that I can't convert the data it gives me to an `NSArray`. It says the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'JSON' to type 'NSArray' in coercion

Here's the code I'm using:

```
if let file = NSBundle(forClass:AppDelegate.self).pathForResource("world", ofType: "json") {
    let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: file)!

    var worldDataGenJSON = JSON(data:data)
    var worldDataGen = worldDataGenJSON as NSArray
} else {
    //error
}
```

I need to convert type `JSON` to `NSArray`

Edit:
The other post did not help my situation. It tells me to type in the same code I'm already using. It's still returning the same error.

Comment: Why do you need to use `as NSArray`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [to Parse JSON to NSArray in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34813387/to-parse-json-to-nsarray-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not use `NSArray` in Swift because it lacks type information.

`SwiftyJSON` has three properties to get an array from a JSON object.

- `array` : returns `[JSON]?`
- `arrayValue` : returns `[JSON]`
- `arrayObject` : returns `[AnyObject]?`

Your code is too ambiguous to know which one is the most suitable.

Comment: How come I can't subscript it?

Comment: `NSArray` doesn't like type information any more or less than `[AnyObject]`.  I agree with the general sentiment of not using `NSArray`, but we should be clear on the reasons.

Comment: @LegoCreeperLeaf Edit your question to provide more information what you are going to accomplish.